# Avoid onClickRow table bootstrap when click on button

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I have a problem cause everytime I click a button inside a column, the onClickRow is triggered in table boostrap, I would like to avoid this if you are clicking a button inside a column.

Answer (score 1):

I write this for people who is using table bootstrap and want to exclude one field of the onClickRow event, for example a column with buttons.

if the field where your buttons are is called 'operate' or 'whatever', as I show you here:

```
        var myColumns = [
        [
        {
            field: 'operate',
            rowspan: 2,
            align: 'center',
        }
        ]
```

you could do it like this:

```
  onClickRow: function (row, $element, field) {
        // row: the record corresponding to the clicked row,
        // $element: the tr element.

        if (field !== 'operate') {

                window.location = someUrl;

        }
    }
```

So if the field is operate it won't do anything.